# How to fetch data from gridview row that is selected?

Tags: c#, gridview

I'm trying to fetch the data from the gridview according to the row I select for deletion.

I tried this,

```
string fileName = grdUploadedFiles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].ToString();
```

but it shows the string,

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell
```

What exactly can I do to fetch the filename that I have inserted to the gridview.

Also, this field is not the DataKey.

Comment: If a answer solve your problem then you should `Accept` it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `cell` not contain any control like `label` then try this

```
string fileName = grdUploadedFiles.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling .Text for the value, per [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfieldcell.aspx).

Generally speaking .ToString is overridden by default for Value types. Reference types generally don't override .ToSting with their "values" (what you would commonly access when calling that class).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeleteeventargs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

    void CustomersGridView_RowDeleting
        (Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell cell = CustomersGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];
        if (cell.Text == "Beaver")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Message.Text = "You cannot delete customer Beaver.";
        }
        else
        {
            Message.Text = "";
        }
    }  

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>GridView RowDeleting Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h3>
        GridView RowDeleting Example
    </h3>
    <asp:Label ID="Message" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="CustomersGridView" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
        OnRowDeleting="CustomersGridView_RowDeleting"
        DataKeyNames="CustomerID,AddressID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" 
                HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
                SortExpression="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" 
                SortExpression="City" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StateProvince" HeaderText="State" 
                SortExpression="StateProvince" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CustomersSqlDataSource" runat="server"
        SelectCommand="SELECT SalesLT.CustomerAddress.CustomerID, 
            SalesLT.CustomerAddress.AddressID, 
            SalesLT.Customer.FirstName, 
            SalesLT.Customer.LastName, 
            SalesLT.Address.City, 
            SalesLT.Address.StateProvince 
            FROM SalesLT.Customer 
            INNER JOIN SalesLT.CustomerAddress 
            ON SalesLT.Customer.CustomerID = 
                SalesLT.CustomerAddress.CustomerID 
            INNER JOIN SalesLT.Address ON SalesLT.CustomerAddress.AddressID = 
                SalesLT.Address.AddressID"
        DeleteCommand="Delete from SalesLT.CustomerAddress where CustomerID = 
            @CustomerID and AddressID = @AddressID" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AdventureWorksLTConnectionString %>">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="AddressID" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" />
        </DeleteParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```